# Proving that central zero of an L-function is multiple

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions

Central point of critical strip, ie. $s=1/2$, is conjectured to be the only argument at which an L-function can have multiple zero. This is interesting ia. for proving effective lower bounds for class numbers of quadratic number fields (probably only degree 2 L-functions work for this purpose) in light of the work of Goldfeld. As far as I'm aware, the only proof method that an L-function of a modular form vanishes at $s=1/2$ uses the fact that it coincides with L-function of an elliptic curve with positive rank. The question is whether it is possible to study multiplicity of central zeros of L-functions of modular forms directly, that is without recourse to arithmetical objects whose L-functions coincide with the former. This question seems to be natural in view of difficulty of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture and the fact the former class of L-functions is perhaps wider than the latter, ie. perhaps there exist modular forms without corresponding arithmetical objects.

Comment: "As far as I'm aware, the only proof method that an $L$-function of a modular form vanishes at (the central point) uses the fact that it coincides with $L$-function of an elliptic curve with positive rank." $ $ One can use modular symbols to show central vanishing (including in the even parity case), and this is significantly easier IMO than using something like Kolyvagin or Coates-Wiles.

Comment: Can you give a reference to any paper which shows/employs this? Thank you!

Comment: I guess you mean a primitive L-function? Cause $\zeta^{2}$ certainly has multiple zeros outside the central argument. Otherwise, it may be the case that the more symmetries of a given L-function preserve the argument, the higher the multiplicity of a zero at this argument can be. Under RH only the critical line can contain non trivial zeros and this line is preserved under both the identity and $s\mapsto 1-\bar{s}$. Similarly the real axis is preserved under both the identity and $s\mapsto\bar{s}$.

Comment: Naturally, a primitive L-function to ever hope for a nontrivial multiple zero.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand some comments: there are numerous examples of $L$ functions of modular forms of weight $4$, say, which have a double zero at $s=2$, and as mentioned by MyNinthAccount this can be proved using modular symbols.

Comment: If it was at least a triple zero and if it was possible to prove this via modular symbols, then a simpler route to effective lower bounds for class number problem would follow, right? So this works only for double zeros so far, right? If yes, then what are the main obstacles to extending?

Comment: Modular symbols allow you to compute the central $L$-value (writing it as a rational divided by an appropriate period, and you can bound the height of the rational, thus giving a criterion for it being zero), but not its derivative. See Section 2.8 of Cremona's book.